# SSL sharing between Apache and Apache tomcat with standard port

Tags: java, wordpress, apache, tomcat, ssl

I have a wordpress application deployed on an Apache server running on port 80 and I also have a java web application deployed on a Tomact server running on port 443.

So basically I have:

**http ://mysite.com (Apache)**

https: //mysite.com/application (Tomcat)

Now I need to start using my SSL certificate for my website. I know that these processes cannot share the same port. Is there a way to keep both urls without adding an extra port? So both can be accessed via:

**https ://mysite.com (Apache)**

**https ://mysite.com/application (Tomcat)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is to mount an Nginx server and manage the redirection according to the URL hit:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain.me;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.domain.me;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://destinationIp:destinationPort;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing this answer on my configuration with Apache in the front of a Tomcat instance.  I don't have your exact configuration but I believe the following should work.

I have an SSL configuration which is where things get forwarded to Tomcat. 
 I've modified it to be what I think you need:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /application http://localhost:8080/application
    ProxyTimeout 360

    # rest of the ssl configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

This should forward everything under `/application` to Tomcat and keep the rest being served by Apache.  Note that this assumes that you have the `proxy` (a.k.a. mod_proxy) module enabled for your server.

Comment: Hey thanks! So this means that if I want to keep everything running over https, I need to change the tomcat or the apache https port?

Comment: Do you need SSL between Apache and Tomcat?  Usually port 8080 would not be accessible to the outside and all traffic would pass through Apache.  However, if you need SSL from Apache to Tomcat then change the `ProxyPass` line to have `https` and the correct host and port.  If not then Apache will handle all traffic and pass through `/application` to Tomcat and Tomcat will send it back through Apache.